# Rails error config_path in kernel_require.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After install Ruby and Rails, I run command 'Rails -v', and got error:

> /home/chuanhtuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- /home/chuanhtuan/config/boot
>   (LoadError)   from
>   /home/chuanhtuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from script/rails:5:in `'

I add 2 line to kernel_require.rb at line 55

```
puts "----------------------------------------"
puts path
```

and out put:

```
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
executable-hooks/hooks
----------------------------------------
rubygems/requirement
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
rubygems-bundler/noexec
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
bundler-unload
----------------------------------------
bundler
----------------------------------------
fileutils
----------------------------------------
etc
----------------------------------------
pathname
----------------------------------------
pathname.so
----------------------------------------
rbconfig
----------------------------------------
bundler/gem_path_manipulation
----------------------------------------
bundler/rubygems_ext
----------------------------------------
pathname
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
rubygems/specification
----------------------------------------
bundler/match_platform
----------------------------------------
bundler/gem_helpers
----------------------------------------
bundler/rubygems_integration
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
rubygems/config_file
----------------------------------------
rubygems/user_interaction
----------------------------------------
io/console
----------------------------------------
rbconfig
----------------------------------------
etc
----------------------------------------
bundler/version
----------------------------------------
bundler/constants
----------------------------------------
bundler/current_ruby
----------------------------------------
rubygems
----------------------------------------
rails/cli
----------------------------------------
rails/app_rails_loader
----------------------------------------
pathname
----------------------------------------
/home/chuanhtuan/config/boot
----------------------------------------
rubygems/requirement
```

I don't know why have a path: '/home/chuanhtuan/config/boot'

I use Ubuntu 14.02LTS

Please support me, thanks!

I install Ruby and Rails by following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl 
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
rvm requirements 
rvm install 2.0.0 
rvm use 2.0.0 --default 
gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: How did you install Rails?

Comment: > sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install curl
> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
> source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
> rvm requirements
> rvm install 2.0.0
> rvm use 2.0.0 --default
> gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc